# Elementary Rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, production

I am trying to deploy my app on Rails for the first time using Heroku.

I have spent quite a lot of time but there's a gap somewhere.

Git: created private repo, pushed to git successfully
Heroku: created free app and pushed successfully (but app 'crashes')
Local:

```
rake db:schema:dump #success
rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production #failure: production database is not configured
rake db:create db:load RAILS_ENV=production #failure: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
  active_record/railties/databases.rake:59:in 'rescue in create_database'
  active_record/railties/databases.rake:39:in 'create_database'
```

My database.yml file:

`defaults: &defaults

  adapter: mysql

  username: root

  password: password

  host: localhost`

`development:

  <<: *defaults

  database: project_dev`

`test:

  <<: *defaults

  database: project_test`

---

Just added:
`production:
  <<: *defaults
  database: project_production`

I may be making a total rookie mistake. Do you know where I might be going wrong?

Comment: where is the production environnment in your database.yml?

Comment: HA! Talk about a rookie mistake. I'm working through this and the suggestions below. Let's see where it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command `heroku rake db:schema:load`, which simply executes the command `rake db:schema:load` on Heroku's environment.

You do not need to worry about the database environments are they are automatically configured by Heroku on the compilation of the slug.

Answer (score 0):

The rake commands which you are running, run on your development machine. If you want to run rake commands on the server, use the heroku command (example):

```
heroku rake db:create
```

Note, if you want to push data, you are doing it wrong. Go to [heroku.com](http://www.heroku.com/) and look at the docs there.